# Identity Principle Question

Tags: complex-analysis

The identity principle states that, if two holomorphic functions on a domain $D$ agree on a set that contains an accumulation point in $D$, then $f \equiv g$.

Define the functions $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by the rules
$$ f(z) = \begin{cases}
z^2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{z} \right), &\text{if } z \neq 0 \\
0, &\text{if } z = 0,
\end{cases} $$
and
$$ g(z) = \begin{cases}
2 z^2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{z} \right), &\text{if } z \neq 0 \\
0, &\text{if } z = 0.
\end{cases} $$
Then $f(z) = g(z)$ if and only if $z = 0$ or $z = \frac{1}{n}$ for some nonzero integer $n$.  Now
$$ \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : f(z) = g(z) \} = \{ 0 \} \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0 \} \right\}. $$
This set has an accumulation point of $0$.  However, $f \not\equiv g$.

What is going on in this example?  Which assumptions of the identity theorem are not satisfied? Are $f$ and $g$ not holomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\sin \frac{\pi}{z}$ has an essential singularity in $0$, that means your functions $f$ and $g$ are not holomorphic. They are not even continuous in $0$, if you approach $0$ through purely imaginary values, $\sin \frac{\pi}{it}$ grows exponentially (in $1/t$), you have $$\sin \frac{\pi}{it} = \frac{1}{i}\sinh \frac{\pi}{t}.$$

Comment: OK.  Say I restrict $f$ and $g$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  The assumptions in the identity principle use the word "domain".  Does this mean "open and connected"?

Comment: Yes, it means open and connected. If you restrict to $\mathbb{R}$, you get functions that are continuously differentiable, but not real-analytic in $0$. The identity theorem holds also for real-analytic functions, but that premise is again not given.